# Return map from HQL query with better optimization

Tags: java, hql

Hi I want to use HQL to return a map now I have following two methods which one consumes less memory or which one is better?

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from UniwareTallySku");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<UniwareTallySku> skuList = (List<UniwareTallySku>) query.list();

    for (UniwareTallySku list : skuList) {
        uniwareSkuVsTallySku.put(list.getUniwareSku(), list.getTallySku());
    }

    return uniwareSkuVsTallySku;
```

The other one is

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select new map(table.columnname2 as c1, table.columnname3 as c2) from UniwareTallySku");
```

which one is better??
Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I feel this as a micro-optimization. Apart from that negligible optimization, you are misusing Hibernate with your manual queries. I am with first way.

Never write queries manually in code. They are DB dependent. And also avoid HQL (*if possible*).

Try using [Criteria API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

Comment: Alright I get the DB dependent part. but i have a doubt whether the criteria will eventually be converted to a SQL query or not.